# Huawei M2-802L Cannot making call!

Tags: calls

i have a Huawei Harman/kardon M2-802L tablet. i want to make calls using sim card. there was no default calling app. i downloaded one, but the device showing :"your device is unable to make calls" when i try to open it.

anyone please advice. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

doing a simple search on the web you find that your tablet only works with voip. Sim card is only for data. You can not call or receive a call.

Comment: Do you have an official source for it? Or maybe a qualified post on xda

Comment: I found it on a thread of stackexchange. As I am connected to Internet with my phone, I can not copy paste the subject of the thread. It mention this link : Source:http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/faq.do?method=getFaqInfo&questionId=7564

Answer (score 0):

By looking around, it is possible.. However you need to make system modifications and literally build your system with a Modem & Call App... The best way I've seen is to actually try porting a firmware from a different tablet with the same chip set, that does have Call abilities..